# SLIM Framework PHP

Tags: php, slim

```
$app->map('/users/posts/:id', function($id) use ($app) {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

        $app->redirect('/action/users/login/');
    }
    else{

        $app->render('something.php');
    }
})->via('GET', 'POST');
```

Hi All, im new with slim php framework. The problem i face now is when i pass parameter id at this url

```
/users/posts/:id ,
```

i want to get the id value when im at something.php page. How can i do that ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Just google "pass variable to view SLIM" and you have tons of answers. If you wan to be good developer before asking try find it by yourself. You can learn more by doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set data in the `$app->render()` method
so something like this:

```
$app->render(
    'something.php',
    array( 'id' => $id )
);
```

In the template you get this variable with:

```
echo $this->data['id'];
```